# Using history.pushState with rails ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on a messaging section in an app and am having some problems with history.pushState. Basically, I have 2 views, one that lists all threads, and one to show a single thread. When a user clicks on a thread (with a link set to remote=true), rails responds with my show.js.erb file. This file includes

```
    $("#layout-body").html("<%=j render :partial => 'thread' %>");
    if (Modernizr.history) { history.pushState("test: testy", null, "<%=j raw message_thread_url(params) %>"); }
```

Currently, when the thread is clicked, the url correctly updates to /messages/ID. However when I hit the back button, the url changes back to /messages, but the page content doesn't change. How do I go about making this work? Am I going about it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

You have to respond to the `popstate` event.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    console.log(location.pathname);
});
```

Comment: yes I read something about that, but my understanding of js is limited & I'm not sure how to use it to update the page when the popstate event is fired. I can update the url fine but the page content is either the same, or a mess of raw js

Comment: When the `popstate` event is triggered, _you_ must change the page contents. It is not automatic as with the normal back button action.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this still doesn't answer my question of how to actually go about changing the page contents

Comment: Not sure how I can this much clearer. When using the HTML history, it gives you a tool, but _you_ have to manage the actual page-changing. Let me give an easy example: suppose you have tabs on a page. When you change tab, you push the tab-name on the url. This to make sure, next time the page refreshes, you can examine the url and see which tab should be current (but you, the code, has to switch to that tab). Likewise, when catching the pop-state, you will get the url, you will have to parse the url to know which tab to switch to. Is that a bit clearer?

Comment: thanks, thats a bit clearer, I just don't know technically how to make this work. Do I just add a javascript redirect inside the popstate event (eg window.location = location.pathname)? Otherwise I would need a separate popstate function for every section of the website right?